# implementing thread using runnable interface in java

Tags: java

Why we have to create an instance of a class and attach it to the newly created thread object even if both are in the same class?

```
import java.io.*;
class thread1 implements Runnable{

   public void run(){
       System.out.println("thread started");
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
      Thread t1=new Thread(new thread1());
      t1.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, because of the `static`ness of `main()`

Comment: why should it be static

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/180100) for more info about the `static` modifier

Comment: @RC. - Thats not because of the static-ness of `main`. Its because, to start a new Thread, you have to create its instance .

Comment: And this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static) for `static main()`

Comment: thanks.is thread a static object

Comment: @TheLostMind I think he's talking about `thread1`

Comment: why can't you create an instance of Thread outside main function.

Comment: @RC. - I am quite confused. Justin, you can do it outside main().

Comment: but I tried to do it but it says thread1.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
t1.start();
        ^

Comment: It is working form me.http://ideone.com/SBku2A

Comment: that's right.But what I want is both the start method and object creation of thread should be outside main().

Comment: outside main means outside main function? Then it should be a class members

Comment: how to make it a class member

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a Runnable to perform custom code within a new Thread. It's also possible to create a subclass of thread directly.

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new WorkerThread().start();

        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        mc.startThread();
    }

    private void startThread(){
        Thread t = new WorkerThread();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: okay that's right.But why can't we create an instance of thread outside main function.

Comment: You can. It was just an example, you can create and start a new thread anywhere. Just like you would instantiate any object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two questions in one:

1.) How to work with a Thread in Java? The answer of Fizer Khan is an example of this.

2.) How do static methods work in java? If you have a static method you are, in a maner of speaking, on a "static layer". You have no "this" reference because there is not object on this layer. Only if you create an instance you can access instance fields and non static methods on this object.
If you add a second static method, you can do the same stuff as in your main method, because both are static. This is rudementary look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402564/how-do-static-methods-work

```
pulblic class Thread1 implements Runnable{ //name should be upper case

public void run(){
    System.out.println("thread started");
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{ //static method
   Thread t1=new Thread(new Thread1()); //t1 is a local reference to an object on the heap - no specil magic here
   t1.start(); //call to an "instance" method, can only be performed on an object.
}
```

Comment: You cannot make an object static only a reference to it. You can have static methods.

Comment: Thats fine, I mean, there is no reason not to do it.

Comment: but i tried to do it but the error is:thread1.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
t1.start();
        ^

Comment: then there is a syntax error or something, but I don't see it in your example.

Comment: okay sorry I gave you the code where the thread was created and started in main().But I would like to see a program where thread is created and started outside main().

Comment: you cannot invoke thread without main static function. Why? Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520497/compilation-error-identifier-expected

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write threads.

```
public class ThreadX implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //Code
    }
}
/* with a "new Thread(new ThreadX()).start()" call */


public class ThreadY extends Thread {
    public ThreadY() {
        super("ThreadY");
    }
    public void run() {
        //Code
    }
}
/* with a "new ThreadY().start()" call */

public class MainClass {
    private Thread threadX = new Thread(new ThreadX());
    private Thread threadY = new ThreadY();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Call threads
        threadX.start();
        threadY.start();

        // some more threads
        new Thread(new ThreadX()).start();
        new ThreadY().start();
    }
}
```

When you extends Threads, You usually extend a class to add or modify functionality. So, if you don't want to overwrite any Thread behavior, then use Runnable.

Comment: could you show me an example of creating and starting a thread object outside main function

Comment: I added code to create instance of thread before main function as class memebers.

Comment: Because, you can instantiate the object as class member. But you need a main function to invoke it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520497/compilation-error-identifier-expected

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for.So is it possible to create a global thread using more than 1 class.