# Why the symbol 'add' cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an array list, but the `add` method is not working.

```
package com.zaination.listview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ListView VarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    ArrayList<String> VarArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    VarArrayList.add("Zain");
    VarArrayList.add("Sarmad");
    VarArrayList.add("Aanish");
    VarArrayList.add("Haider");

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because your code that is adding the items to the array list in not in a method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Identifier expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected)

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520497/compilation-error-identifier-expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would put that code into onCreate (or any other) method it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

it's need to be updated like this.

```
package com.zaination.listview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView VarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
ArrayList<String> VarArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
VarArrayList.add("Zain");
VarArrayList.add("Sarmad");
VarArrayList.add("Aanish");
VarArrayList.add("Haider");
}
```

}

also another hint attr name `VarArrayList` not follow java naming convention, should start with small letter `varArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the code outside of any method. It has to be in any kind of method.

The easiest way is to write it directly into the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView VarListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    ArrayList<String> VarArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    VarArrayList.add("Zain");
    VarArrayList.add("Sarmad");
    VarArrayList.add("Aanish");
    VarArrayList.add("Haider");
}
```

---

**PS**:
There are some small improvements (also partly recommended by Android Studio) you could do:

- you can ommit the cast `(ListView)` because it's redundant
- you can ommit the ArrayList identifier `string` on initialization
- you should name your objects (like `VarArrayList`) after the [lower camel case](https://wiki.c2.com/?LowerCamelCase) naming convention (`varArrayList`):

[image]